# Is it possible to ask yum/dnf to ignore duplicate files (rocky 8)?

Tags: yum, dnf, rocky-os

We have code base with many RPMs.  One RPM has a binary named foo.  Foo is a bit like busybox, a binary that we connect to with many symbolic links.  There is one special function that, for permissions reasons (sticky bit), we COPY the binary to, call it 'bar', when installing a different RPM.

The problem I've encountered since we started working with rocky 8, is that yum recognizes that bar and foo are identical (it keeps some kind of hash in a .build_id subdirectory), throws an error, and fails.  I can use 'rpm -i --force my.rpm' but I'd prefer not to.

Have I missed a yum/dnf option?

Thank you,
Mike

I tried a hard link but that throw a different error.  I can use RPM directly but want proper package management.

Comment: A colleague pointed out the obvious solution of building a second 'foo-sticky' in the initial RPM that we could link to when we need the sticky bit set.  So that's my solution (and probably a smarter choice to begin with) but I'll leave the question open.